# How to transfer variable between multiple files when DOM is involved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to store some data into mysql. The flow is like:
First, in my `table.js` generate a table like following.

```
function tableBody() {
let tr; //table <tr>
let td; //table <td>
let tblBodyContent = document.getElementById('tableBodyContent');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for (let col = 0; col < 6; col++) { 
        if (col === 5 && i > 5) break; 
        td = document.createElement('td')
        td.innerHTML = 'cell value here';
        let cellID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        td.setAttribute('id', cellID);
        td.addEventListener('click', cellClick);
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tblBodyContent.appendChild(tr);
}}
function cellClick() {
   let tableCellId = this.id;
   window.open("./form.html")}
```

Each cell in the table is clickable, when a cell is clicked, it will open `form.html`, the `form.html` code as following:

```
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="test">
          <p>desplay the cellID</p>
        </div>
            <form action="user_input" method="POST">
                <label for="inputname">Name</label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputfistname" name="inputfistname" placeholder="Firstname">
                    </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div></body>
```

When submit button is clicked, I want to store two pieces of data into mySql, the code `storeData.js` as following:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const { prohairesis } = require('prohairesis');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysqlConnect = require('./mysqlConnect')

const app = new express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app
.use(morgan('short'))
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
.use(express.static('./'))

.post('/user_input', (req, res) => {
    const cellId = ''; //I'm stucked here: tableCellId from test.js
    const firstName = req.body.inputfistname;

    const queryString = 'INSERT INTO userinfo VALUE (?,?)';
    mysqlConnect.connection.query(queryString, [firstName, cellId], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`the error is ${err}`)
            res.send(500);
            throw err;
        }
    })
})
.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I am stuck here because one data `cellId` which is a random number generated in `table.js` cellClick function `tableCellId`, Since my `table.js` contains DOM elements, so I can't use `require('./table.js')` in my `storeData.js`, is there a way that I can call this variable from `table.js` in my `storeData.js`? So I can store it in mySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With LocalStorage. First, set your cellClick function like this:

```js
function cellClick() {
   let tableCellId = this.id;
   window.localStorage.setItem('cell_id', tableCellId);
   window.open("./form.html")
}
```

Later, when form.html is loaded. Load the value from LocalStorage cell_id into a hidden input.

```html
<form action="user_input" method="POST">
  <label for="inputname">Name</label>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputfistname" name="inputfistname" placeholder="Firstname">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_cell_id" value="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  document.querySelector('input[name="input_cell_id"]').value = window.localStorage.getItem('cell_id');
</script>
```

In your node.js, you get the value the same way as the first name.

```js
const cellId = req.body.input_cell_id;
```